# Подключение по ssh при сборке с использованием Jenkins

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста.

Использую Jenkins для сборки проекта, который работает в докер контейнере и столкнулся с проблемой.

При выполнении данного куска кода:

```
    stage('deploy front') {
        when { equals expected: 'do', actual: buildFront }
        agent {docker{image 'ebiwd/alpine-ssh'}}

        steps{
            sh 'chmod 400 .iac/privatekey'
            sh "ssh -i   .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163 'cd /opt/docker/test && docker-compose pull nginx && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps nginx '"
        }
    }
```

получаю ошибку:

> + ssh -i .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163
>
> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>
> Warning: Permanently added '134.209.181.163' (ECDSA) to the list of
> known hosts.
>
> bind: No such file or directory

При этом если выполнить следующий скрипт руками в контейнере, то все работает

```
ssh -i   .iac/privatekey ci_user@134.209.181.163
```

сам контейнер запускаю с помощью docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.277.1-lts
    container_name: jenkins
    hostname: jenkins
    restart: always
    user: root
    privileged: true

    ports:
      - 172.17.0.1:8070:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как минимум проблема в том, что используя команду в такой форме, вы указываете ssh запустить интерактивную сессию из скрипта, т.е. из контекста, который не предполагает интерактивности. Из консоли у вас запускается shell и все работает, а что вы ожидаете от этой команды при запуске из Jenkins скрипта?

Comment: На самом деле изначально скрипт немного длиннее, я его сократил пытаясь локализовать ошибку. Изначальный скрипт сейчас верну отредактировав вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно использовать этот скрипт без интерактивности?